# How to create checkbox multiselect dropdown in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to create a checkbox multi-select dropdown list in WordPress. I am using Contact form 7 plugin.

Answer (score -1):

**Checkbox, Checkbox* and Radio**

Both checkbox and checkbox* represent a group of checkboxes ( in HTML). checkbox* requires the user to check at least one of the boxes.

radio represents a group of radio buttons ( in HTML). Note that there is no required version of radio (“radio*”). The reason Contact Form 7 doesn’t provide “radio*” is because a radio button is a required field by nature. The HTML spec document explains it more in detail.

**Example:**

```
[checkbox your-country "China" "India" "San Marino"]
```

Source:  https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/